# Some devices not receiving pushnotification in android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

In my application i'm using GCM. Two devices successfully registered in GCM server. When i send notification to devices. one device getting notification and another one not getting notification

I can get success from GCM server.

```
 MulticastResult(multicast_id=5801304151550412167,total=2,success=2,failure=0,canonical_ids=0,results: [[ messageId=0:1401798089476787%e15813d800000031 ], [ messageId=0:1401798089477704%e15813d800000031 ]]
```

Manifest.Xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.mothersgroupie.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.mothersgroupie.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

 <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.mothersgroupie" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.mothersgroupie.GCMIntentService" />
```

Comment: What version is the device that doesn't get the notification? Can you post the manifest?

Comment: @Eran Samsung s3 not receiving notification. I have edited my post

Comment: one device in India another one in Australia. Indian device receiving notification Australian device not receiving. Really i don't know the reason

Comment: What Android version is the device that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Some issues to check in the device:

1_ Has Google Play installed?

2_ Has a valid google account and logged in?

3_ Has internet connection working.?

4_ Other notification, like gmail ones arrives?

Comment: Another thing is to make sure ports 5228, 5229, and 5230 are open for its network.